# Highcharts using JSON – Border and label colors

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am using Highcharts in the JSON format. The syntax is below:

```
var neutral_color = '#c4c4c4',
    medium_grey = '#929292';

lineChartJSON['chart']['plotBorderColor'] = medium_grey;
lineChartJSON['chart']['plotBorderWidth'] = 1;
lineChartJSON['chart']['zoomType'] = 'xy';

lineChartJSON['yAxis']['gridLineColor'] = medium_grey;
lineChartJSON['yAxis']['gridLineWidth'] = 1;
lineChartJSON['yAxis']['labels'] = { style: { color: neutral_color} };

lineChartJSON['xAxis']['lineColor'] = medium_grey;
lineChartJSON['xAxis']['lineWidth'] = 1;
lineChartJSON['xAxis']['tickColor'] = medium_grey;
lineChartJSON['xAxis']['labels']['style'] = { color: neutral_color };
lineChartJSON['xAxis']['title']['style'] = { color: neutral_color };
```

I am trying to get the border style around the columns to be null or the same color as the background color. Right now they are default white. And for the xAxis and yAxis labels, I'd like to control that color as well. They are both default #666 now.

The documentation refers to a different data format, so I am kind of poking around in the dark here. While `lineChartJSON['yAxis']['labels'] = { style: { color: neutral_color} };` does not work, it also does not give me a console error, while this format does: `lineChartJSON['yAxis']['labels']['style'] = { color: neutral_color};`. The error is how this element is not defined.

For the record, `'lineColor` and `tickColor` work.

Any good guides or pointers out there for interpreting the Highcharts array syntax for JSON vs. JS?

Comment: Can you refer to the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j0Lepver/)? I used the code you shared and it works - can you adjust it to show the issue?

Comment: I see that, and I also see that xAxis has the same `labels` option. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels So why when I copy your code and change `yAxis` to `xAxis` does the fiddle stop rendering? I was originally trying to get both axis of labels to be the same color.

Comment: Because xAxis object does not exist and you are trying to access property of undefined - to access a property of an object - the object must be initialised. http://jsfiddle.net/j0Lepver/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ugh… so I ended up using CSS to style the parts that I couldn't figure out how to access through the API. I had to use a lot of `!important` declarations because Highcharts puts so much inline on the SVG elements, but it got me where I wanted to go.